# How to require one pod per minion/kublet when configuring a replication controller?

Tags: label, kubernetes

I have 4 nodes (`kubelets`) configured with a label `role=nginx`

```
master ~ # kubectl get node
NAME          LABELS                                          STATUS
10.1.141.34   kubernetes.io/hostname=10.1.141.34,role=nginx   Ready
10.1.141.40   kubernetes.io/hostname=10.1.141.40,role=nginx   Ready
10.1.141.42   kubernetes.io/hostname=10.1.141.42,role=nginx   Ready
10.1.141.43   kubernetes.io/hostname=10.1.141.43,role=nginx   Ready
```

I modified the replication `controller` and added these lines

```
spec:
  replicas: 4
  selector:
    role: nginx
```

But when I fire it up I get 2 pods on one host. What I want is 1 pod on each host. What am I missing?

Comment: I have added another tag to the rc yaml file  "nodeSelector: role: nginx" still not able to get the rc to place 1 nginx contianer on each node when the number of replicas is set to 4.

Answer (score 8):

Prior to DaemonSet being available, you can also specify that you pod uses a host port and set the number of replicas in your replication controller to something greater than your number of nodes. The host port constraint will allow only one pod per host.

Comment: Robert's answer is technically correct.  hostPorts can only be allocated once per node, so it will have the side-effect that you want.  Pod `spec.containers[*].ports[*].hostPort`.

Comment: I said "technically correct" because this is sort of an anti-pattern.  In most cases you should not need to schedule one-per-node, but it's hard to say more without a full dump of your app architecture :)  We generally encourage people to not think about nodes - just think about your app and how it naturally wants to be organized.

Comment: what about having a fluentd-es container running on each node to aggregate logs ? we sort of need exactly one on each node.

Comment: Logging is one use case for pod-per-node. But keep in mind that you can also implement logging using a sidecar container in the same pod as your application pod-per-node isn't strictly required to enable application logging.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to achieve this by modifying the labels as follows below

```
master ~ # kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME          LABELS                                           STATUS
10.1.141.34   kubernetes.io/hostname=10.1.141.34,role=nginx1   Ready
10.1.141.40   kubernetes.io/hostname=10.1.141.40,role=nginx2   Ready
10.1.141.42   kubernetes.io/hostname=10.1.141.42,role=nginx3   Ready
10.1.141.43   kubernetes.io/hostname=10.1.141.43,role=nginx4   Ready
```

I then created 4 nginx replication controllers each referencing the nginx{1|2|3|4} roles and labels.

Comment: Can you do it using a single replication?

Answer (score 1):

Replication controller doesn't guarantee one pod per node as the scheduler will find the best fit for each pod. I think what you want is the [DaemonSet controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/design/daemon.md), which is still under development. Your workaround posted above would work too.

Comment: DaemonSet is the right way to do this *eventually*.  It's just not ready for prime time yet.